# Dataframe Joining Columns based on date within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried search around for an answer but most was based on merging 2 dataframe, however mine exist within a single dataframe

```
D1date     D1price  D2date     D2price
1/2/2017   11.4     1/3/2017   11.3
1/3/2017   12.4     1/4/2017   12.3
1/4/2017   14.4     1/5/2017   12.4
1/5/2017   15.5     1/6/2017   12.5
```

Results I am looking for

```
D1date     D1price   D2price
1/2/2017   11.4      nan
1/3/2017   12.4      11.3
1/4/2017   14.4      12.3
1/5/2017   15.5      12.4
```

Can any kind souls advise me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) + [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.filter(like='D1').join(df.filter(like='D2').set_index('D2date'), on='D1date')
print (df)
     D1date  D1price  D2price
0  1/2/2017     11.4      NaN
1  1/3/2017     12.4     11.3
2  1/4/2017     14.4     12.3
3  1/5/2017     15.5     12.4
```

Comment: I want to ask a question... although my dataframe is D1price, D1 works but D1price do not... why?

Comment: Csm you rxplain more? What return `print(df.filter(like='D1'))`?  It should filter all columns with `D1`.

Comment: sorry I should ask another question, if my dataframe do not have a consistent header but for example, Date2 highlow Date3 close ... using filter will not work in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately not, then need `df = df[['D1date', 'D1price', 'another col']].join(df[['D2date', 'D2price', 'another col 1']].set_index('D2date'), on='D1date')
print (df)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
df[['D1date', 'D1price']].merge(df[['D2date', 'D2price']], how='left', left_on='D1date', right_on='D2date')
```

You can add:

```
.drop('D2date', axis=1)
```

To remove `D2date` column.
Complete code:

```
df = df[['D1date', 'D1price']].merge(df[['D2date', 'D2price']], how='left', left_on='D1date', right_on='D2date').drop('D2date', axis=1)
```

Comment: this returns me the same table, the table did not change

Comment: Of course it hasn't, you have to assign it to `df` variable.